# Should I recommend ASMX because WCF is overkill?

Tags: wcf

Of course you might argue that ASMX is not easier than WCF. But let's just agree it is. And, think about it. The whole pipeline is simpler. Yes, some features/behaviors are not available to ASMX.

**But for a normal, run-of-the-mill, handful-of-methods, projects is WCF overkill?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No - why??**

Especially with WCF in .NET 4 (read [A Developer's Introduction to Windows Communication Foundation 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)), it's **just as easy to use** as ASMX - but it's not "legacy" and doesn't constrain you to just a single protocol (HTTP) and hosting mode (IIS). It gives you lots of room to grow and adapt, if needed.

With .NET 4, WCF needs a lot less config to get started - literally no config at all, if you're happy with default settings. It's a lot easier to get up and running, the Visual Studio template are better and more extensive - I see **absolutely** no reason to invest even a second into a "dead" and very restrictive technology like ASMX anymore.

Comment: I think an argument could be made that ASMX is easier to write and easier to deploy than WCF. Even version 4.

Comment: @Jerry Nixon: then we are at a disagreement - I think WCF 4 is just as easy as ASMX, but it also offer much more - so for me, the choice is clear.

Comment: Okay, I'll agree with you 90% - that's enough.